# Toggle a boolean value with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, optimization, boolean, toggle

I'm working with a mongoDB database and I want to toggle the boolean present attribute inside the Day object. Here is my working code:

```
exports.modifyPresence = (req, res) => {
  action.getStudentCurrentDay(req.body.hash)
  .then(
    dayId => {
      return Day.findOne({_id: dayId});
    }
  )
  .then(
    day => {
      return Day.findOneAndUpdate({_id: day.id},{$set:{present:!day.present}});
    }
  )
  .then(
    () => res.status(200).json("This is a success")
  )
  .catch(
    (error) => res.status(500).json({error})
  )
}
```

It's working but I would have loved to call my db once and write something like this:

```
exports.modifyPresence = (req, res) => {
  action.getStudentCurrentDay(req.body.hash)
  .then(
    dayId => {
      return Day.findOneAndUpdate({_id: day.id},{$set:{present:!present}});
    }
  )
  .then(
    () => res.status(200).json("This is a success")
  )
  .catch(
    (error) => res.status(500).json({error})
  )
}
```

Do anyone knows how to implement a single call to the database and toggle my boolean in an elegant way? I have no clues how to simplify my code.

Thank you all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2, you can use aggregation operators in your update statement, like:

```
.findOneAndUpdate({_id: day.id},[{$set:{present:{$eq:[false,"$present"]}}}]);
```

That will set `present` to true if it is false, and to false if it is any other value.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2,

- [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/) Evaluates a boolean and returns the opposite boolean value; i.e. when passed an expression that evaluates to true, `$not` returns false; when passed an expression that evaluates to false, `$not` returns true.

```
return Day.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: day.id },
  [
    { $set: { present: { $not: "$present" } } }
  ]
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-8WqwxxV3h-)

Comment: This also has the effect of not modifying the `present` field if it does not contain a boolean.  I don't know which way the asker intended.

Comment: yes you are right `$not` evaluates as false the following: `null`, `0`, and `undefined` values and other as true. your answer is really accurate solution. actually i looked duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932581/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-bulk-toggle-boolean-value-in-mongodb) and i vote for close and referred this question as duplicate.