# What is the most efficient way to bulk toggle boolean value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use aggregation pipeline and $not operator to bulk update fields of matched documents, but its not working.
I know  but don't want to use js loop to modify them as it is inefficient way to do that.

```
    let result = await User.updateMany(
        {_id: {$in: ids}},
        [{
            $set: {isActive: {$not: ["$isActive"]}}
        }]
        )
```

Comment: just remove the [] `[{$set: {isActive: {$not: "$isActive"}}}]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle a boolean value with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104727/toggle-a-boolean-value-with-mongodb)