# Mongo DB query nested filter

Tags: mongodb

I have this Mongo DB document structure...

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63b6e12d650c56ca2e720c86"
  },
  "userName": "Harshit Gupta ",
  "email": "harshitguptapositive@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2b$10$Ys0AfxbtQKX3XytM1n85dO0dUL2bFAMQiD3w5nSw6zFmda4W4yRn6",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "habbitName": "Jogging",
      "Description": "defended",
      "Sunday": false,
      "Monday": true,
      "Tuesday": false,
      "Wednesday": true,
      "Thursday": false,
      "Friday": true,
      "Saturday": false,
      "Month": [
        {
          "date": 0,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c8d"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 1,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c8e"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 2,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c8f"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 3,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c90"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 4,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c91"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 5,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c92"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 6,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c93"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 7,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c94"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 8,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c95"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 9,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c96"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 10,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c97"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 11,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c98"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 12,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c99"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 13,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c9a"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 14,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c9b"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 15,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c9c"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 16,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c9d"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 17,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c9e"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 18,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c9f"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 19,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca0"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 20,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca1"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 21,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca2"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 22,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca3"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 23,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca4"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 24,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca5"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 25,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca6"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 26,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca7"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 27,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca8"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 28,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720ca9"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 29,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720caa"
          }
        },
        {
          "date": 30,
          "done": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720cab"
          }
        }
      ],
      "timeRemind": "23:12",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63b6e14c650c56ca2e720c8c"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1672929612245"
        }
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1672929612245"
        }
      }
    }
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1672929581689"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1672939914562"
    }
  },
  "__v": 2
}
```

I want to first select user id then specific the task id and the document which gets selected then
I want to update specific date of the month field can you please suggest the specific query..

first select select user by user id then a task by task id then in Month field i want to update a n element(done attribute to true) whose date is 4.

I tried to apply the following operation.

```
let doc = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: req.user.id
    }
    ,{
      "tasks.$[task].Month.$[dateIndex].done": true
    },{
      arrayFilters:[ {"dateIndex.date" : 4} ,{"task.id":req.params.taskId}]
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The positional parameter `$` only matches the first element of the top-most array.

To update within an object in an array nested in another array, use arrayFilters and the [$[]](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) positional filter to refer into the nested arrays, like:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id),
  "tasks._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.taskId)
},
{$set: {"tasks.$.Month.$[m].done": true}},
{
  arrayFilters: [{"m.date": dateIndice}]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AJmO01fT2st)

Comment: The playground link shows the update part works, perhaps you need to case `req.user.id` and `req.params.taskId` to ObjectId first? I'll edit that into the answer

Comment: Your solution worked can you please also tell me how invert the value of boolean done that is make true to false and false to true

Comment: [Toggle a boolean value with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104727/toggle-a-boolean-value-with-mongodb)

Comment: i tried with $not operator it threw an error

Comment: $set:{"tasks.$.Month.$[dateIndex].done": {$not : "$tasks.$.Month.$[dateIndex].done" }}

Comment: Ask that as a new question, comments don't really work for exploring a new problem